# Need help advancing to a new level and having more enemies spawn

Tags: javascript, html

Currently i have two zombies spawn in once i start the game, issue im currently having and need help with is when i kill those first two zombies. 4 new zombies are supposed to spawn in but they dont. Still new here and i really need yall help thank you.

```
let zombieDeaths = 0;
const zombies = [];

let yellowZombies = []; 
let zombieTwos = [];

let yellowZombieDeaths = 0;
let zombieTwoDeaths = 0;

function decreaseZombieHealth(zombie, amount) {
  zombie.health -= .2;

  if (zombie.health <= 0) {
    zombie.health = 0; 
    handleZombieDeath(zombie); 
    updateLifeBar(zombie);
  }
}

function handleZombieDeath(zombie) {
  if (zombie === yellowZombie) {
    yellowZombieDeaths++; 
  } else if (zombie === zombieTwo) {
    zombieTwoDeaths++; 
  }

  checkZombieDeaths();
}

function checkZombieDeaths() {
  if (yellowZombieDeaths >= 2 && zombieTwoDeaths >= 2) {
    console.log('New Level');
    spawnNewZombies(); 
    yellowZombieDeaths = 0; 
    zombieTwoDeaths = 0; 
  }
}

function spawnNewZombies() {
  for (let i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    const randomXYellow = Math.random() * canvas.width;
    const randomYYellow = Math.random() * canvas.height;

    const newYellowZombie = {
      x: randomXYellow,
      y: randomYYellow,
    };

    yellowZombies.push(newYellowZombie);
    console.log('new yellow zombie spawned')

  }

  for (let i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    const randomXTwo = Math.random() * canvas.width;
    const randomYTwo = Math.random() * canvas.height;

    const newZombieTwo = {
      x: randomXTwo,
      y: randomYTwo,
    };

    zombieTwos.push(newZombieTwo);
    console.log('new green zombie spawned')

  }
}
```

Im not sure what else to try

Answer (score 0):

You are spawning two zombies at the begginning, but you are checking if yellowZombies and zombieTwo are greater 1.

```
if (yellowZombieDeaths >= 2 && zombieTwoDeaths >= 2) {
```

so this will be never true. Either you spawn in the beginning also zombieTwo two times or do the check with an or operator.

```
if (yellowZombieDeaths >= 2 || zombieTwoDeaths >= 2) {
```

Comment: just added the if statement that you suggested and looks like that didnt do the trick. Even though i am getting the console logs. Im about to pull my hair out lol

Comment: Then now its a different issue, and your first issue is done, as you see the logs statement :)

Comment: how do you check, if the zombies are there?

Comment: currently using this function, but its not logging , this is alot of work smh https://pastebin.com/0jeccjmU

Comment: where is yellowZombie and zombieTwo coming from? 
function handleZombieDeath(zombie) {
  if (zombie === yellowZombie) {
    yellowZombieDeaths++; 
  } else if (zombie === zombieTwo) {
    zombieTwoDeaths++; 
  }

  checkZombieDeaths();
}